# f convex function proof if and only if g convex function for x and d

Tags: convex-analysis

Theorem 1. A function $f : R^n \rightarrow R$ is convex if and only if the function $g : R \rightarrow R$ given
by $g(t) = f(x + ty)$ is convex (as a univariate function) for all $x$ in domain of $f$ and all
$y$ $2$ $R^n$. (The domain of $g$ here is all $t$ for which $x + ty$ is in the domain of $f$.)

I can't proof it

Comment: If you just spell out the definitions of convex, it is impossible not to prove it

Comment: Could you explain ? @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: Suppose $f$ is convex. Then show from the definition of $g$ that $g$ is convex. Then do the other way around.

Comment: f(tetha*x+(1+tetha)*y)<=tetha*f(x)+(1-tetha)f(y). and then ? @copper.hat

Comment: Could help please ? @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: Could help please ? @copper.hat

Comment: You need to try something. It really is a matter of transcription.